# DateTimePicker: Use neither calendar nor spin button

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0, datetimepicker

I want to take advantage of `DateTimePicker`'s date validation, but the calendar seemed cumbersome to our customers for setting the date (they'd rather do it using just the keyboard, tabbing their way through the form).

So I took a long look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.showupdown.aspx) and found that one way to get rid of the calendar was setting the `ShowUpDown` property to true. So I got this:

[image]

However, our customers are now saying that they don't want to use the spin button, and therefore they don't want it to be visible/accesible. i.e. they want this:

[image]

However, if i set `ShowUpDown` to false, I'm back to the calendar. Is there another way?

Comment: The only other way I found was to create your own custom control.  I needed a Date Picker where the user had to explicitly press the "down" icon to open the calendar.  So the default behavior when tabbing to the control was to enter the date via keyboard.  I also wanted the ability for the user to choose no date (Nullable Of Date).

Comment: Looks that way. Why couldn't they just add an enum property for this? With the {Calendar/SpinButton/None} values.

Comment: Did you use inheritance or composition? Or did you just roll the whole thing yourself?

Comment: I just created it myself using a textbox and button control inside a user control.  The button drops down a MonthCaledar control.  I had to do all the validations myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to roll my own Custom Control. Luckily, some other guy from the team has already written custom controls so I have example code to get started. Anyway, what good is a framework if I have to do this kind of things myself? Hope they solved this in .net 4.5...

**EDIT**: Using a MaskedTextBox with `ValidatingType = typeof(System.Date)` is a better solution. Sorry .NET!